# Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagewebp()

Tags: php, gd

I have an exception while trying to call imagewebp function.
Official php manual includes this function, I have enabled php_gd2.dll extension, but i cant use this function

what's the problem? Am I have old version of the gd lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of php are you using? You can use ImageWebp from php5..[PHP](http://php.net/manual/it/function.imagewebp.php)

And control that you were follow every step in configuration: [GD configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Comment: Yep, thanks my php version is younger - v5.3.

Comment: So, did you resolve your trouble?@АлександрПономарев

Comment: No, because according to the manual imagewebp() 
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagewebp.php
needs PHP version 5.5, but the latest stable version is 5.4.15
So it means that I cant use this function now?

Comment: No, you can use this function in you version, i'm using it, read the page at my second link and try to reconfigure it following those steps. @АлександрПономарев

Comment: For anyone reading this now, the minimum PHP version required is 5.4 according to the docs. Not sure what they would have said at the time. Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagewebp.php